# Cuales son las novedades en php 8?

Tags: php, php8

Faltan pocos días para el lanzamiento oficial de `PHP 8`.

¿Cuáles son las novedades de `PHP 8`?

Comment: Acá pueden consultar la lista completa: https://wiki.php.net/rfc#php_80 igual puedes considerar agregarlo a tu respuesta

Answer (score 4):

Traducción de parte del artículo [**What's new in PHP 8**](https://stitcher.io/blog/new-in-php-8) publicado por Brent.

**[PHP 8](https://www.php.net/releases/8.0/en.php)**<sup>1</sup> se lanzará el [26 de noviembre de 2020](https://wiki.php.net/todo/php80). Es una nueva versión mayor, lo que significa que introducirá algunos cambios importantes, así como muchas características nuevas y mejoras de rendimiento. En este momento, PHP 8 está congelado, lo que significa que ya no se pueden agregar nuevas funciones.

Debido a los cambios importantes, existe una gran probabilidad de que necesites realizar algunas modificaciones en tu código para que se ejecute en PHP 8. Si te has mantenido actualizado con las últimas versiones, la actualización no debería ser demasiado difícil, ya que la mayoría de los cambios importantes fueron obsoletos antes en las versiones 7.*. Y no te preocupes, todas estas bajas se enumeran en esta publicación.

Además de los cambios importantes, PHP 8 también trae un buen conjunto de nuevas características como el compilador JIT, tipos de unión, atributos y más.

## Nuevas características

Comencemos con todas las funciones nuevas, ¡es una gran lista!

### Tipos de unión [rfc](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/union_types_v2)

Dada la naturaleza de tipo dinámico de PHP, hay muchos casos en los que los tipos de unión pueden ser útiles. Los tipos de unión son una colección de dos o más tipos que indican que se puede utilizar cualquiera de ellos.

```
public function foo(Foo|Bar $input): int|float;
```

Ten en cuenta que `void` nunca puede ser parte de un tipo de unión, ya que indica "ningún valor de retorno". Además, las uniones que aceptan valores `NULL` se pueden escribir usando `| null`, o usando la notación `?` existente:

```
public function foo(Foo|null $foo): void;

public function bar(?Bar $bar): void;
```

### JIT [rfc](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/jit)

El compilador JIT, –Just in Time– (justo a tiempo), promete importantes mejoras de rendimiento, aunque no siempre en el contexto de las solicitudes web. <sup>2</sup>

### El operador nullsafe [rfc](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/nullsafe_operator)

Si estás familiarizado con el [operador de fusión nula](https://stitcher.io/blog/shorthand-comparisons-in-php#null-coalescing-operator), ya estás familiarizado con sus defectos: no funciona en llamadas a métodos. En su lugar, necesita verificaciones intermedias o confiar en ayudantes opcionales proporcionados por algunos marcos:

```
$startDate = $booking->getStartDate();

$dateAsString = $startDate ? $startDate->asDateTimeString() : null;
```

¡Con la adición del operador nullsafe, ahora podemos tener un comportamiento similar a la fusión nula en los métodos!

```
$dateAsString = $booking->getStartDate()?->asDateTimeString();
```

Puedes leer todo sobre el operador nullsafe [aquí](https://stitcher.io/blog/php-8-nullsafe-operator).

### Argumentos con nombre [rfc](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/named_params)

Los argumentos con nombre permiten pasar valores a una función, especificando el nombre del valor, para que no tengas que tener en cuenta su orden, ¡y también puedes omitir parámetros opcionales!

```
function foo(string $a, string $b, ?string $c = null, ?string $d = null) 
{ /* … */ }

foo(
    b: 'value b', 
    a: 'value a', 
    d: 'value d',
);
```

Puedes leer sobre ellos en profundidad [en este post](https://stitcher.io/blog/php-8-named-arguments).

### Atributos [rfc](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/attributes_v2)

Los [atributos](https://stitcher.io/blog/attributes-in-php-8), comúnmente conocidos como anotaciones en otros lenguajes, ofrecen una forma de agregar metadatos a las clases, sin tener que analizar docblocks.

Podemos echar un vistazo rápido a cómo se ven los atributos, mediante un ejemplo del RFC:

use App\Attributes\ExampleAttribute;

```
#[ExampleAttribute]
class Foo
{
    #[ExampleAttribute]
    public const FOO = 'foo';
 
    #[ExampleAttribute]
    public $x;
 
    #[ExampleAttribute]
    public function foo(#[ExampleAttribute] $bar) { }
}



#[Attribute]
class ExampleAttribute
{
    public $value;
 
    public function __construct($value)
    {
        $this->value = $value;
    }
}
```

Ten en cuenta que este `Attribute` base solía llamarse `PhpAttribute` en el RFC original, pero luego se cambió por [otro RFC](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/attribute_amendments). Si deseas profundizar en cómo funcionan los atributos y cómo puedes crear los tuyos propios; puedes leer sobre los atributos en profundidad en [este blog](https://stitcher.io/blog/attributes-in-php-8).

### Expresión de coincidencia (Match expression) [rfc](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/match_expression_v2)

Podríamos llamarlas la hermana mayor de la expresión de cambio: la coincidencia puede devolver valores, no requiere declaraciones de interrupción, puede combinar condiciones, usa comparaciones de tipos estrictas y no hace ningún tipo de coerción.

Se parece a esto:

```
$result = match($input) {
    0 => "hello",
    '1', '2', '3' => "world",
};
```

Puedes leer sobre la expresión de coincidencia en detalle, [aquí](https://stitcher.io/blog/php-8-match-or-switch).

### Constructor de promoción de propiedad [rfc](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/constructor_promotion)

Este RFC agrega azúcar sintáctico (syntactic sugar) para crear objetos de valor u objetos de transferencia de datos. En lugar de especificar propiedades de clase y un constructor para ellas, PHP ahora puede combinarlas en una.

En lugar de hacer esto:

```
class Money 
{
    public Currency $currency;
 
    public int $amount;
 
    public function __construct(
        Currency $currency,
        int $amount,
    ) {
        $this->currency = $currency;
        $this->amount = $amount;
    }
}
```

Ahora podremos hacer esto:

```
class Money 
{
    public function __construct(
        public Currency $currency,
        public int $amount,
    ) {}
}
```

Hay mucho más que contar sobre la promoción de propiedades, puedes leer sobre ellas en [esta publicación](https://stitcher.io/blog/constructor-promotion-in-php-8).

### Nuevo tipo de retorno estático [rfc](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/static_return_type)

Si bien ya era posible devolver `self`, `static` no era un tipo de retorno válido hasta PHP 8. Dada la naturaleza de tipo dinámico de PHP, es una característica que será útil para muchos desarrolladores.

```
class Foo
{
    public function test(): static
    {
        return new static();
    }
}
```

### Nuevo tipo mixto rfc

Algunos podrían llamarlo un mal necesario: el tipo mixto (`mixed`) hace que muchos tengan sentimientos encontrados. Sin embargo, hay un buen argumento a favor: un tipo faltante puede significar muchas cosas en PHP:

- Una función devuelve nada o nula
- Esperamos uno de varios tipos
- Estamos esperando un tipo que no se puede insinuar en PHP

Debido a las razones anteriores, es bueno que se agregue el tipo `mixed`. `mixed` en sí mismo significa uno de estos tipos:

- array
- bool
- callable
- int
- float
- null
- object
- resource
- string

Ten en cuenta que `mixed` también se puede utilizar como parámetro o tipo de propiedad, no solo como tipo de retorno.

También ten en cuenta que dado que `mixed` ya incluye `null`, no está permitido convertirlo en `nullable`. Lo siguiente provocará un error:

```
// Fatal error: Mixed types cannot be nullable, null is already part of the mixed type.
function bar(): ?mixed {}
```

### Throw expression (Lanzar expresión) [rfc](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/throw_expression)

Este RFC cambia de ser una declaración a ser una expresión, lo que hace posible lanzar una excepción en muchos lugares nuevos:

```
$triggerError = fn () => throw new MyError();

$foo = $bar['offset'] ?? throw new OffsetDoesNotExist('offset');
```

### Herencia con métodos privados [rfc](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/inheritance_private_methods)

Anteriormente, PHP solía aplicar las mismas comprobaciones de herencia en métodos públicos, protegidos y privados. En otras palabras: los métodos privados deben seguir las mismas reglas de firma de métodos que los métodos protegidos y públicos. Esto no tiene sentido, ya que las clases secundarias no podrán acceder a métodos privados.

Esta RFC cambió ese comportamiento, por lo que estas comprobaciones de herencia ya no se realizan en métodos privados. Además, el uso de `final private function` tampoco tenía sentido, por lo que ahora se activará una advertencia:

```
Warning: Private methods cannot be final as they are never overridden by other classes
```

### Weak maps (Mapas débiles) [rfc](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/weak_maps)

Construidos sobre el [RFC de thinrefs](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/weakrefs) que se agregó en PHP 7.4, se agrega una implementación de `WeakMap` en PHP 8. `WeakMap` contiene referencias a objetos, lo que no evita que esos objetos sean recolectados como basura.

Tomemos el ejemplo de los ORM, que a menudo implementan cachés que contienen referencias a clases de entidad para mejorar el rendimiento de las relaciones entre entidades. Estos objetos de entidad no pueden recolectarse como basura, siempre que esta caché tenga una referencia a ellos, incluso si la caché es lo único que hace referencia a ellos.

Si esta capa de almacenamiento en caché usa referencias y mapas débiles en su lugar, PHP recolectará estos objetos cuando ya no haya nada más que haga referencia a ellos. Especialmente en el caso de los ORM, que pueden gestionar varios cientos, si no miles, de entidades dentro de una solicitud; los mapas débiles pueden ofrecer una forma mejor y más amigable de manejar estos objetos.

Así es como se ven los mapas débiles, un ejemplo del RFC:

```
class Foo 
{
    private WeakMap $cache;
 
    public function getSomethingWithCaching(object $obj): object
    {
        return $this->cache[$obj]
           ??= $this->computeSomethingExpensive($obj);
    }
}
```

### Permitiendo `::class` en objetos [rfc](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/class_name_literal_on_object)

Una característica nueva, pequeña pero útil: ahora es posible usar `::class` en objetos, en lugar de tener que usar `get_class()` en ellos. Funciona de la misma forma que `get_class()`.

```
$foo = new Foo();

var_dump($foo::class);
```

### Capturas sin captura [rfc](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/non-capturing_catches)

Cuando se quería capturar una excepción antes de PHP 8, había que almacenarla en una variable, independientemente de si se usó esa variable o no. Con capturas sin captura, puedes omitir la variable, así que en lugar de esto:

```
try {
    // Something goes wrong
} catch (MySpecialException $exception) {
    Log::error("Something went wrong");
}
```

Ahora puedes hacer esto:

```
try {
    // Something goes wrong
} catch (MySpecialException) {
    Log::error("Something went wrong");
}
```

Ten en cuenta que es necesario especificar siempre el tipo, no se permite tener una captura vacía. Si deseas capturar todas las excepciones y errores, puedes usar `Throwable` como el tipo de captura.

### Coma final en listas de parámetros [rfc](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/trailing_comma_in_parameter_list)

Ya era posible cuando se llamaba a una función, pero aún faltaba el soporte de coma final en las listas de parámetros. Ahora está permitido en PHP 8, lo que significa que puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
public function(
    string $parameterA,
    int $parameterB,
    Foo $objectfoo,
) {
    // …
}
```

Como nota al margen: las comas finales también se admiten en la lista de uso de cierres, esto fue un descuido y ahora se agregó a través de una [RFC separada](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/trailing_comma_in_closure_use_list).

### Crear objetos DateTime desde una interfaz

Ya puedes crear un objeto `DateTime` a partir de un objeto `DateTimeImmutable` usando `DateTime::createFromImmutable ($immutableDateTime)`, pero al revés fue complicado. Al agregar `DateTime::createFromInterface()` y `DateTimeImmutable::createFromInterface()`, ahora hay una forma generalizada de convertir objetos `DateTime` y `DateTimeImmutable` entre sí.

```
DateTime::createFromInterface(DateTimeInterface $other);

DateTimeImmutable::createFromInterface(DateTimeInterface $other);
```

### Nueva interfaz para cadenas (Stringable) [rfc](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/stringable)

La interfaz `Stringable` se puede usar para escribir sugerencias a cualquier cosa que implemente `__toString()`. Siempre que una clase implementa `__toString()`, implementa automáticamente la interfaz detrás de escena y no hay necesidad de implementarla manualmente.

```
class Foo
{
    public function __toString(): string
    {
        return 'foo';
    }
}

function bar(string|Stringable $stringable) { /* … */ }

bar(new Foo());
bar('abc');
```

### Nueva función `str_contains()` [rfc](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/str_contains)

Algunos podrían decir que está retrasado, pero finalmente ya no tenemos que depender de `strpos()` para saber si una cadena contiene otra cadena.

En lugar de hacer esto:

```
if (strpos('string with lots of words', 'words') !== false) { /* … */ }
```

Ahora puedes hacer esto:

```
if (str_contains('string with lots of words', 'words')) { /* … */ }
```

### Nuevas funciones `str_starts_with()` y `str_ends_with()` [rfc](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/add_str_starts_with_and_ends_with_functions)

Otras dos funciones que se habían retrasado hace mucho tiempo, ahora se agregan en el núcleo de PHP.

```
str_starts_with('haystack', 'hay'); // true
str_ends_with('haystack', 'stack'); // true
```

### Nueva función `fdiv()` [pr](https://github.com/php/php-src/pull/4769)

La nueva función `fdiv()` hace algo similar a las funciones `fmod()` e `intdiv()`, lo que permite la división por 0. En lugar de errores, obtendrás `INF`, `-INF` o `NAN`, según el caso.

### Nueva función `get_debug_type()` [rfc](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/get_debug_type)

`get_debug_type()` devuelve el tipo de variable. ¿Suena como algo que haría gettype()? `get_debug_type()` devuelve resultados más útiles para matrices, cadenas, clases anónimas y objetos.

Por ejemplo, llamar a `gettype()` en una clase `\Foo\Bar` devolvería un objeto. El uso de `get_debug_type()` devolverá el nombre de la clase.

Puedes encontrar una lista completa de las diferencias entre `get_debug_type()` y `gettype()` en el RFC.

### Nueva función `get_resource_id()` [pr](https://github.com/php/php-src/pull/5427)

Los recursos son variables especiales en PHP que se refieren a recursos externos. Un ejemplo es una conexión MySQL, otro un identificador de archivo.

A cada uno de esos recursos se le asigna una identificación, aunque anteriormente la única forma de saber esa identificación era lanzar el recurso a `int`:

```
$resourceId = (int) $recurso;
```

PHP 8 agrega las funciones `get_resource_id()`, lo que hace que esta operación sea más obvia y segura de escribir:

```
$resourceId = get_resource_id($recurso);
```

### Métodos abstractos en mejoras de rasgos [rfc](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/abstract_trait_method_validation)

Los rasgos pueden especificar métodos abstractos que deben ser implementados por las clases que los utilizan. Sin embargo, hay una advertencia: antes de PHP 8, la firma de estas implementaciones de métodos no se validaba. Lo siguiente era válido:

```
trait Test {
    abstract public function test(int $input): int;
}

class UsesTrait
{
    use Test;

    public function test($input)
    {
        return $input;
    }
}
```

PHP 8 realizará la validación adecuada de la firma del método cuando utilices un rasgo e implementes sus métodos abstractos. Esto significa que necesitarás escribir esto en su lugar:

```
class UsesTrait
{
    use Test;

    public function test(int $input): int
    {
        return $input;
    }
}
```

### Implementación de objeto de `token_get_all()` [rfc](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/token_as_object)

La función token_get_all () devuelve una matriz de valores. Esta RFC agrega una clase PhpToken con un método PhpToken :: tokenize (). Esta implementación funciona con objetos en lugar de valores simples. Consume menos memoria y es más fácil de leer.

### Ajustes de sintaxis variable [rfc](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/variable_syntax_tweaks)

De la RFC: "La RFC de sintaxis de variable uniforme resolvió una serie de inconsistencias en la sintaxis de variables de PHP. Esta RFC intenta abordar un pequeño puñado de casos que se pasaron por alto".

### Anotaciones de tipo para funciones internas [externals.io](https://externals.io/message/106522)

Mucha gente [contribuyó](https://github.com/php/php-src/pulls?q=is%3Apr%20label%3AStubs%20is%3Aclosed) para agregar anotaciones de tipo adecuadas a todas las funciones internas. Este era un problema de larga data y finalmente se podía resolver con todos los cambios realizados en PHP en versiones anteriores. Esto significa que las funciones y métodos internos tendrán información de tipo completa reflejada.

### `ext-json` siempre disponible [rfc](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/always_enable_json)

Anteriormente era posible compilar PHP sin la extensión JSON habilitada, esto ya no es posible. Dado que JSON se usa tan ampliamente, es mejor que los desarrolladores siempre puedan confiar en que estará allí, en lugar de tener que asegurarse de que la extensión exista primero.

---

### Cambios definitivos

Como se mencionó anteriormente: esta es una actualización importante y, por lo tanto, habrá cambios importantes. Lo mejor que puedes hacer es echar un vistazo a la lista completa de cambios importantes en el documento [ACTUALIZACIÓN](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/PHP-8.0/UPGRADING#L20).

Sin embargo, muchos de estos cambios importantes han quedado obsoletos en las versiones 7.* anteriores, por lo que si te has mantenido actualizado a lo largo de los años, no debería ser tan difícil actualizar a PHP 8.

A continuación voy a listar los principales, poniendo al lado el enlace al RFC, sin describirlos, porque sería una respuesta enorme que agotaría el espacio:

- Errores de tipo consistente [rfc](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/consistent_type_errors)
- Advertencias del motor reclasificadas [rfc](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/engine_warnings)
- El operador `@` ya no silencia los errores fatales
- Nivel de informe de errores predeterminado: Ahora es `E_ALL`. Esto significa que pueden aparecer muchos errores que anteriormente se ignoraban en silencio, aunque probablemente ya existían antes de PHP 8.
- Modo de error PDO predeterminado [rfc](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/pdo_default_errmode)
- Precedencia de concatenación [rfc](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/concatenation_precedence)
- Verificaciones de tipo más estrictas para operadores aritméticos y bit a bit [rfc](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/arithmetic_operator_type_checks)
- Los nombres con espacios de nombres son un solo token [rfc](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/namespaced_names_as_token): PHP solía interpretar cada parte de un espacio de nombres (separada por una barra invertida ) como una secuencia de tokens. Esta RFC cambió ese comportamiento, lo que significa que los nombres reservados ahora se pueden usar en espacios de nombres.
- Cadenas numéricas más sanas [rfc](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/saner-numeric-strings) : El sistema de tipo PHP intenta hacer muchas cosas inteligentes cuando encuentra números en cadenas. Este RFC hace que ese comportamiento sea más coherente y claro.
- Cadena más sana para comparaciones numéricas [rfc](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/string_to_number_comparison): Este RFC corrige el caso muy extraño en PHP donde `0=="foo"` da `true`. Hay algunos otros casos extremos como ese, y este RFC los corrige.
- Cambios en la firma del método de Reflection
- Clasificación estable [rfc](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/stable_sorting): Antes de PHP 8, los algoritmos de clasificación eran inestables. Esto significa que el orden de elementos iguales no estaba garantizado. PHP 8 cambia el comportamiento de todas las funciones de clasificación a clasificación estable.
- Error fatal para firmas de métodos incompatibles [rfc](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/lsp_errors)
- Otros elementos obsoletos y cambios:

  Durante el desarrollo de PHP 7.*, se agregaron varias funciones obsoletas que ahora están finalizadas en PHP 8.

  - Obsoleto en [PHP 7.2](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/deprecations_php_7_2)
  - Obsoleto en [PHP 7.3](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/deprecations_php_7_3)
  - Obsoleto en [PHP 7.4](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/deprecations_php_7_4)
  - [Conversión de float a string](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/locale_independent_float_to_string) independiente de Local

---

### Notas

1. No hay por ahora versión en castellano, cuando la haya podremos escogerla donde dice `Change language` (en la parte superior  derecha de la página).
2. Ver algunos [benchmarks](https://stitcher.io/blog/jit-in-real-life-web-applications) sobre JIT hechos por el autor del artículo. Si deseas saber más sobre lo que JIT puede hacer por PHP, puedes leer [esta publicación](https://stitcher.io/blog/php-jit).

Comment: Considero que puedes agregar en tu respuesta, la landing page de PHP 8 que acompaña su lanzamiento hoy, https://www.php.net/releases/8.0/en.php donde también se anexa información sobre lo nuevo del lenguaje

Comment: @BetaM gracias, agregado. Muy buen enlace.

Answer (score 1):

Este 26 de noviembre se viene PHP en su versión 8 y aquí te contare de algunos cambios.

### Nullsafe operator

En nuestras `class` siempre tenemos funciones que se relacionan con otras `class`, por ejemplo un **Post** tiene **Categorias** y de esta necesitamos solo el nombre del primero, y para dicha acción realizamos algo similar a esto:

```php
$name_first_posts=null;
if($posts != null){
    if($posts->categories() != null){
        if($posts->categories()->first() != null){
            $name_first_posts=$posts->categories()->first()->name();
        }
    }
}
```

Que pensarías si te digo que: `!= null` ahora puede ser reemplazado por `?`. Veamos el anterior ejemplo con **nullsafe operator**:

```php
$name_first_posts=$posts?->categories()?->first()?->name;
```

Esto es de locos!!!, ambos códigos hacen exactamente lo mismo.

### ::class en objetos

El `::class` solo funciona en referencia a las clases, es decir supongamos que tenemos la clase **Post**, entonces solo podíamos hacer algo como esto:

```php
use app\model\Post;
Post::class //
```

Pero ahora podemos aplicarlo a los objetos de clase:

```php
use app\model\Post;
$post = new Post()//
var_dump(Post::class);
var_dump($post::class);
var_dump(Post::create()::class);
```

Todos los `var_dump` muestran lo mismo. chévere!!!

### throw exception

Veamos un poco de como lanzar excepciones con un **nullsafe operation**:

```php
//antes
$post=null;
if($post != null){
    echo $post;
}
else{
    throw new Exception();
}
// ahora con php 8
echo $post ?? throw new Exception();
```

Y que hay de esas `try-catch` en donde siempre teníamos que capturar el error en una variable, de la cual ni hacíamos uso:

```php
//antes
$post=null;
try{
    if($post != null){
        echo $post;
    }
    else{
        throw new Exception();
    }
}
catch(Exception $no_lo_usare){
      echo "Error!!!";
}
```

Ahora, combinemos este ejemplo con el anterior para obtener un resultado mas simplificado:

```php
try{
    $post ?? throw new Exception();
}
catch(Exception){//si no necesito la variable ya no la creo
    echo "Error!!!";
}
```

No se a usted, pero a mi me parece hermoso.

### Class constructor property promotion

Y seguimos acortando el codigo, al crear una `class` **Post** por ejemplo, hacemos:

```php
class Post {
    private string $name;
    private string $id;
    public function __construct(string $id, string $name) {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->id = $id;
    }
}
```

Pero ahora la nueva sintaxis seria:

```php
class Post {
    public function __construct(private string $id,private string $name) {}
}
```

What? me quede sin palabras, aunque las `{}` no me acaban de convencer, pero en general se ve bien(fue mi opinion). Y aun hay más.

Podemos crear una instancia de **Post** con los nombre de argumento.

### Name Argument

Entonces ahora podemos instanciar una clase de la siguiente forma:

```php
$post = new Post(
    name:"Novedades en php 8",
    id:"sjaneXoemIUkd"
);
```

Y si te lo preguntas; SÍ, el orden no importa, los valores se asignaran según los nombres de argumento.

Y terminamos con algo que me parece lo mejor de esta actualización.

### Match Expressions

Imaginate que un `switch` y un `JSON` se juntaron y dieron a luz a un `match`, pondre el ejemplo y deslumbrate:

```php
//un switch
$message="";
switch ($statusCode) {
    case 200:
    case 300:
        $message = null;
        break;
    case 400:
        $message = 'not found';
        break;
    case 500:
        $message = throw new ServerError();
        break;
    default:
        $message = 'unknown status code';
        break;
}

// y Ahora con un match
$message=match($statusCode) {
    200, 300 => null,
    400 =>  'not found',
    500 => throw new ServerError(),
    default => 'unknown status code',
};
```

A buen entendedor pocas palabras.

Estos no son todos los cambios pero ya les echamos un vistazo.

Posts original: https://ulaav.com/blog/desarrollo-web/novedades-en-php-8