# Que problema tendria al cambiar de la version PHP 5.6 a una mas reciente

Tags: php, xampp

Espero alguien me pueda dar un norte.

En donde trabajo, el servidor de producción se encuentra actualmente en la versión 5.6 de PHP, en estos momentos tengo instalado el PHP 5.6 y Xammp v3.2.2 , quiero hacer debug, no puedo, al momento de hacer la petición del debuger en el PHPStorm me indica que no existe el contenido de la pagina , existe algún problema si de manera local me cambio a la versión 7 de PHP para poder actualizar el xdebug....dll y poder realizar el debug, realmente esto podría afectar el desarrollo que estoy realizando al momento de llevarlo a producción ? .

Alguien que me pueda orientar ?

De antemano gracias

Saludos

Comment: Tu pregunta realmente es muy amplia y no se ajusta a [ask], ¿fallar cosas?, si claro y te tocaría tal vez reeescribir algunas de ellas pero sin contexto solo podemos decirte si o no

Comment: Te recomiendo leer lo siguiente: https://www.php.net/manual/es/migration70.php

Comment: @JuanRivera Gracias,pues veo que si existen algunos cambios,  creo que no me quedara de otra que realizar una instalación en un equipo con Linux y php 5.6 , y migrar mi equipo de desarrollo a la versión 7 y probar , ver que sucede. Antes de llevar el código al servidor de producción.

Comment: OJO [PHP 8](https://www.php.net/releases/8.0/en.php) salió hace muy poco y trae muchas novedades considerables ([revisa esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/409247/29967)). Ya que vas a migrar, recomendaría que te vayas a la versión 8 directamente.

Comment: @A.Cedano Un gusto leerte, precisamente quería ver si podría platicar contigo al respecto,  voy a revisar detenidamente lo que me comentas, ya que precisamente al descargar xammp me traje la versión 8 xampp-windows-x64-8.0.2-0-VS16-installer y estuve a punto de instalarla, pero no había hecho respaldo de nada, asi que apenas si logre pulsar cancelar.

Comment: Y bueno de experiencia del pasado, me puse a buscarle que podría hacer con el xdebug, y recordaba que había un repositorio de xdebug para versiones anteriores y escarbándole un poco, y ahora si a prueba y error, que crees que encontré una versión que ya no me tira la pagina.  Al menos de momento he podido realizar un debug a tres segmentos de código sin que me tire el error de que la pagina no se encuentra.  Lo único que si, es que muy a mi pesar, el phpmyadmin sigue lento, no carga tan rápidamente, como lo hace si omites el xdebug en el php ini.

Comment: Cesarín aquí ya es tarde, si quieres podemos charlar mañana. De todos modos no tengo experiencia PHP en Xammp ni en entornos locales, yo programo directamente para mí sitio web que reside en un hosting compartido. PHPMyAdmin en mi caso era insufrible (desde cPanel, en un hosting compartido es lentísimo) no sé si en local es mejor ¿? Lo cierto es que para la Base de Datos me conecto desde la consola (desde la terminal de mi equipo) y ejecutó allí las consultas SQL y va rapidísimo. Y para procesos repetitivos o muy complejos programé scripts PHP MUY PROTEGIDOS y administro muchas cosas ...

Comment: ... en mi sitio remoto desde esos scripts. En cuanto a la perdida de archivos y de datos, conviene que establezcas una política de backup. Es relativamente fácil hacerlo mediante SSH por ejemplo y lo puedes lanzar cada X tiempo con un Cron. Puedes también sincronizar con alguna carpeta en la nube o cosas así por si hay una catástrofe en tu equipo local.

Comment: @A.Cedano Gracias lo voy a considerar lo de la nube, por que también un disco duro que tengo para respaldar, últimamente se esta comportando extraño,  finalmente la electrónica y mecánica  tienden a fallar tarde que temprano.  Igual a lo mejor una formateada ya esta muy cargado.