# Insertar respuesta de bd a input de formulario

Tags: php, html, mysql, html5

Tengo un formulario con un boton buscar, y mi idea es que lo que trae con una condicion, se lo envie a todos los campos de mi formulario.

En el formulario tengo un boton buscar, agregar y modificar, en el boton buscar desearia que se llenen todos los datos recojidos que obtuve en php, el boton agregar y modificar son dos formularios diferentes, estan separados por modal.

```
include("conexion.php");

  if (isset($_POST['buscar'])) {

  $equipo=(trim($_POST["equipo"])) ?? null;

  $consulta = "SELECT tipo, marca, modelo, seri, loca, oficina, piso, departamento FROM tablaequipos WHERE equipo='$equipo'";
  $result = mysqli_query($conex, $consulta);

  if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {

      while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo "Tipo: " . $row["tipo"]. " Marca: " . $row["marca"]. " Modelo: " . $row["modelo"].  " Serial: " . $row["seri"]." Local: " . $row["loca"]. " Oficina: " . $row["oficina"]. " Piso: " . $row["piso"]. " Departamento: " . $row["departamento"]. "<br>";
      }
    } else {
      echo "No hay datos de este equipo";
    }
  }
```

Lo que hace esto es que me trae los datos de lo que busco, pero como se podria insertar al input

Comment: Los resultados se leen dentro del  `while`, ahí tú puedes llenar los  `input` del formulario. Lo que no queda claro es si hablas del mismo formulario que manda a buscar esos datos, en cuyo caso lo mejor sería usar Ajax o la nueva API Fecth de Javascript. Creo que deberías aclarar mejor tu pregunta pulsando en [edit], pues hay cosas que no se entienden.

Comment: No entendí tu comentario. Por favor pulsa en [edit] para aclarar tu duda.

Comment: Tengo un formulario donde tengo un boton buscar, cuando busco un equipo en particular se me va al php con los datos, tipo, marca, modelo, etc. La cuestion es que no quiero que vayan para el php sino que queden ahi cargados en el mismo form

Comment: Para eso tendrías que precargarlos la primera vez, sea con atributos `data-`, o bien guardar los datos en el cliente con algo como localStorage.

Comment: Perfecto, investigo lo que me has dicho, sabes de algun libro para aprender html y php? uno q valga la pena?

Comment: Más que html y php, tendrías que aprender Javascript y PHP, pues html no es otra cosa que un lenguaje de etiquetas (que tiene lo suyo también, pero no tiene mayor misterio). Antes que un libro, puedes ir viendo el mismo Manual de PHP, que tiene traducción en español y muy buenos ejemplos. Y para Javascript el sitio de MDN, también con casi todo en español y buenos ejemplos. Luego, cuando conozcas lo básico puedes leer un libro si quieres... el problema de los libros es que, tratándose de algo que evoluciona tan pronto, quedan obsoletos, salvo casos muy concretos ...

Comment: ... de libros que son referentes en cuanto a aprendizaje de fundamentos de programación. Y es que por ejemplo hace poco PHP lanzó la versión 8, puede que haya libros excelentes de PHP 5 o PHP 7, pero en cuanto a PHP en sí mismo, muchas de las cosas tratadas en esos libros ya son obsoletas y lo único que te pueden aportar es si tratan sobre maneras correctas de programar, porque [PHP 8 vino a cambiar muchas cosas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/409286/29967).

Comment: Aquí tienes el [Manual de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/index.php), y este es el sitio de [MDN sobre Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript), aquí puedes ver [MDN tomando HTML como punto de partida](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML) o [MDN desde el punto de vista de Desarrollo Web](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn). Todos esos son **sitios de referencia**, a los cuales **tendrás que volver una y otra vez**, releer, ver los ejemplos, etc, cuando tengas que implementar algo. Es decir, no es que los lees una vez y ya te lo sabes todo.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu tiempo, estoy aprendiendo por la mia y no se por donde arrancar, pero quiero hacer una web para un relevamiento de equipos